# Animation and Rotation on circluar view in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have created a circular frameLayout, inside this frameLayout i have another view which an icon of charactor , in my code i'm rotating that circular layout each 1 second by -45 degress continousely , the issue that i have run into is that while the circle is rotating , it rotates the icon inside as well , is there anyway to prevent it from rotating , Thank you in advance for any help .

- This is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/download"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:translationY="40dp"
            />

    </FrameLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/animate"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
        android:text="animate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.536"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- This is the code used to rotate circle

```
 animate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pulsateIcon();

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        rotateCircle();
                        handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
                    }
                },1000);

            }
        });

 private void rotateCircle() {

        // this rotates circle each 1 second by -45 degress
        ViewPropertyAnimator viewPropertyAnimator =  circle.animate().rotationBy(-45);
        viewPropertyAnimator.start();
        
        // i want to stop this view from rotating as it rotates with circle
        icon.animate().rotationBy(0f);

    }

    private void pulsateIcon(){
         if(!isPulsating){
             isPulsating = true;
             ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(icon,
                     PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX",1.4f),
                     PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY",1.4f));
             objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
             objectAnimator.setDuration(2500);
             objectAnimator.start();
             objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                 @Override
                 public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                     super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                     pulsateIcon();
                 }
             });
         } else {
             isPulsating = false;
             ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(icon,
                     PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX",1.0f),
                     PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY",1.0f));
             objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
             objectAnimator.setDuration(2500);
             objectAnimator.start();
             objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                 @Override
                 public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                     super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                     pulsateIcon();
                 }
             });
         }
     }
```

Comment: Have the circle at same level inside a new layout . right now circle contains the icon thats the problem . Use a new layout as wrapper.. `FrameLayout(outer)-> FrameLayout(circle) + ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

The ImageView rotates with the FrameLayout I dont see how u can prevent it. however u can rotate the ImageView by the same amount but in the opposite direction.

```
private void rotateCircle() {
    // this rotates circle each 1 second by -45 degrees
    ViewPropertyAnimator circleAnimator = circle.animate().rotationBy(-45);
    circleAnimator.start();

    // counteract the rotation on the icon
    ViewPropertyAnimator iconAnimator = icon.animate().rotationBy(45);
    iconAnimator.start();
}
```

Comment: I was going to comment the same

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys , this answer did not work